# Where is the best place to put common (library) code for Netlify functions

Tags: netlify, netlify-function

Often I have code reused by multiple Netlify functions in the same project.

I know that anything within my `/functions` directory will become a function so I don't want to nest directories there. I could include it in `/src`, but if feels odd to comingle source with my single-page app (SPA) since they have different dependencies.

Is there a good convention for where to put this code? I can't seem to find any answer to this in any of Netlify's documentation.